# How do i find distance between one place to another using Geolocation or Similiar API without embedding a Google Map?

Tags: geolocation, google-places-api

I am having a list of tourist locations with me and i am willing to write a service that could tell me which tourist location is nearest to me and then second nearest and likewise without using a map. How can i do it. The idea is that i have a database of all the tourist locations in a city and their lat/long, I may be in any place in the city and want to find which tourist attraction is nearest to me and second nearest and like wise so that i may plan to visit them based on how much time i have. I tried this and found google maps api but i dont want to display a map for the same. Or give users map to search things.

Comment: Is this to be implemented in JavaScript?

Comment: Yes i want to use javascript; but language is not a restriction here.

Comment: how are you getting the list of tourist attractions ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're not going to display a map, then you can't use Google Maps API (it violates their TOS).

If you are looking to get the lat/lon from an address without Google Maps or similar (because similar services have similar TOS) then you'll want to look for something like [LiveAddress API](https://smartystreets.com/products/apis/us-street-api) (and apparently I'm supposed to disclose that I work at [SmartyStreets](https://smartystreets.com))

This example works for US addresses. International addresses require a different API.

An API like the US Street Address API doesn't require you to show a map, returns geo coordinates, and will verify the validity of the address as it returns its payload.

Here's a [Javascript example](https://smartystreets.com/archive/jquery-plugin/website).

```html
    <script type="text/javascript" src="liveaddress.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    LiveAddress.init(123456789); // API key

    // Make sure you declare or obtain the starting or ending lat/lon somewhere.
    // This example only does one of the points.

    LiveAddress.geocode(addr, function(geo) {
        var lat2 = geo.lat, lon2 = geo.lon;

        // Distance calculation from: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27928/how-do-i-calculate-distance-between-two-latitude-longitude-points
        var R = 6371; // Radius of the earth in km
        var dLat = (lat2-lat1).toRad();  // Javascript functions in radians
        var dLon = (lon2-lon1).toRad(); 
        var a = Math.sin(dLat/2) * Math.sin(dLat/2) +
                Math.cos(lat1.toRad()) * Math.cos(lat2.toRad()) * 
                Math.sin(dLon/2) * Math.sin(dLon/2); 
        var c = 2 * Math.atan2(Math.sqrt(a), Math.sqrt(1-a)); 
        var d = R * c; // Distance in km
    });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need Google maps.

1. Get the user's location via the [geolocation API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Using_geolocation).
2. Map over the list of points, augmenting your object with the distance between the user and the point as calculated using the [great-circle distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great-circle_distance) algorithm.
3. Sort the list via the distance.

Comment: I dont want to get the user's location automatically; I want user to add his location in a textfield and look for options. Because i want the user to be able to search for and suggest other users also. I may give him a option to do a "find my location" thing.

Comment: The user will type their own lat and lon? I think you over estimate how keen tourists are to know about their surroundings. You can use the Google Maps API to get lat/lon from a human readable address.

Comment: Lets say somebody asks me where can i visit today I am in x Location, So i can use this service type his x location and find out all the nearest places to him. I didnt get your point abt over estimation.

Comment: Great Circle Distance only gives areal distance between two locations, There may be a case that no road route exists between these two places.

Comment: @sushilbharwani Then you will need to use an API such as Google Maps API.

Comment: yes but then it embeds a map in the system, is there something else where i do not have a map. Just the distance calculations.

Comment: @sushilbharwani You don't need to show the user a map to use the Google Maps API.

Comment: I found this https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/distancematrix for calcluating distance with google maps but it says its necessary needs to show google maps.